# th:value="${Drop down with spl Chars}" doesnot evaluate

Tags: expression, thymeleaf, spaces

I have a thyme leaf expression th:value="${Drop down with spl Chars}"
It gives follwoing error during its evaluation
ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: Drop down with spl Chars
        at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:112)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.parseExpression(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:225)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:117)
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: ognl.ParseException: Encountered "  "down "" at line 1, column 6.
Was expecting one of:

Answer (score 0):

You can't have variable names with spaces in them.  You should switch to camel case or snake case.